# WPF - Translucent application

Tags: wpf, transparency

My goal: Similarly the Intellisense dropdown in Visual Studio 2008, when the user presses CTRL, I want the entire application to become 40% opaque. How can I do that?

I want to use the regular window chrome, so my WindowStyle cannot be "None".

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For WPF, one possible solution is the custom GlassWindow found in the [FluidKit](http://fluidkit.codeplex.com/) library (CodePlex). In this solution, Window is subclassed and retemplated. Additional work is done to make sure minimize, maximize, and window movement work as expected. I think that there are other custom solutions out there that do similar things.

This is not a perfect solution for a number of reasons, so I am curious to see what others have tried or come up with.

Comment: Richard, thanks! This is very helpful in case I need to go the BorderStyle=None route.

Comment: I am accepting this as an answer since what I wanted is not possible and I actually ended up using GlassWindow.

Answer (score 1):

In WPF, Window.Opacity = 0.4.
In WinForms, Form.Opacity = 40.

Do you use a special tool or setting that your VS gets transparent when pressing Ctrl? It doesn't work for me..

Comment: I think he means IntelliSense and other inline helps when editing source code which do get transparent when holding down Ctrl.

Comment: That also applies to tooltips, and possibly the exception helper too. Have fun trying to catch either of them in a screenshot, when ctrl makes them transparent and alt moves focus away so they disappear. :P

Comment: Johannes, thanks - I am referring to intellisense. I've edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: eWolf, I've tried Window.Opacity but it didn't work: It sets the contents of the window to be transparent, but whatever is behind the application is still not visible.